# docker postgres role does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am using postgres with docker and having trouble with it. I successfully docker-compose up --build

When I run below command it works fine. psql starts with my_username user as expected. I can see my database, \l, \dt commands works ok.

> docker-compose exec db psql --username=my_username
> --dbname=my_database

But when I run below commands I get error ***role “postgres” does not exist***,
Additionally \l, \dt not works, even **psql** command not works

> docker exec -it my_db_container_1 bash
>
> su - postgres
>
> createuser --createdb --password new_user

How can I get it right in the second case? What is going wrong? I am confused

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  #### other services ####
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my_database
      POSTGRES_USER: my_username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
    ports:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/


volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have changed the default username/database/password that the postgres database is initialized with by providing the `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_DB`, and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` environment variables.  When you run `createuser` without a `-U` option, it tries to connect as the current user (postgres in this case) which doesn't exist on the database because you initialized it with the user `my_username`.  The reason `docker-compose exec db psql --username=my_username --dbname=my_database` works is because you are correctly supplying the username and database names that the database was initialized with.

If you remove the `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_DB` environment variables, it will initialize with the defaults postgres/postgres.

**Note** that because you are mounting a volume into this container, which will now have an initialized database in it already, it will not be reinitialized even if you restart your compose.  You need to `docker volume rm` that volume in order to have the database be reinitialized when you start the container.